# Не вешается обработчик событий на компонент react

Tags: reactjs

Есть простенькое приложение на реакт. Это его App.js

```
function App() {

  const show = () => {
    console.log('hello');
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="game-container">
        <Title />
        <CardBoard cards={cards} />
        <Button onClick={() => show()}>начать заново</Button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Собственно есть компонент Button.

```
const Button = ({ children }) => {
  return <button className="button-restart">{children}</button>;
};
```

Вешаю onClick на Button и оно не работает. Никак не могу понять почему в консоль ничего не выводится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы передаёте свойство onClick но не задействуете его.
Достаньте из пропсов Button-а свойство onClick и добавьте кнопке

```
const Button = ({ children, onClick }) => {
  return <button onClick={onClick} className="button-restart">{children}</button>;
};
```